# Jquery new Date - Convert to yyyy-MM-dd and use toLocaleDateString

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have a HTML input box set to type=date

```
<input name="datereceived" type="date" class="FormDateValues" id="datereceived" />
```

I want to use Jquery to fill this input box on document load to today's date but because I am in Australia, I have to offset using GMT+10

To get the date, I do the following:

```
var newDate = new Date();
```

and then I tried to set the input box using the following:

```
$('#datereceived').val(newDate.toLocaleDateString());
```

The browser tells me that for type=date, the format must be set to yyyy-MM-dd and not the Australian time format of dd/MM/yyyy.

I am not sure how to go about enforcing the toLocaleDateString AND converting the date to yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: 1. Australia has more than one time zone. 2. Currently Sydney is on DST which is +11 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `String.prototype.split()` , `Array.prototype.splice()` , `Array.prototype.join()`

```js
// create array of values returned by `.toLocaleDateString()`,
// delimited by `/`
var d = new Date().toLocaleDateString().split("/"); 
// `y` : year
var y = d.splice(-1)[0];
// set `y` as item at index `0` of `d`
d.splice(0, 0, y);
// join items within `d` with dash character `"-"`
var date = d.join("-");
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Will this work on a computer with Germany locale where date is serapated with dots e.g. 19.10.2015 ? :-)

Comment: @MaksymKozlenko Is day `"19"` returned before first dot , or month `"10"` ?

Comment: new Date().toLocaleDateString("de") --> "19.10.2015"

Comment: @MaksymKozlenko No , solution at post will not return same results for `new Date().toLocaleDateString("de") // --> "19.10.2015"` . Could adjust `.split()` `RegExp` to `/\/|\./` , call `d.reverse()` before `d.splice(0, 0, y);` to return same results http://jsfiddle.net/xdnyf9q8/

Comment: Why not to use `new Date("2015-09-01").toLocaleDateString("en-au")` ? It will be diffucult to cover all possible locales. Check output for "ko", "zh" and "th" locales. For last one current year is 2558

Comment: @MaksymKozlenko _"Why not to use `new Date("2015-09-01").toLocaleDateString("en-au")` ?"_ ? Read Question at OP ?

Comment: First of all Australia has 3 times zones. +10 means EST (Sydney/Melbourne). At this moment we are on Daylightsavings time which is +11 hours.

Comment: @MaksymKozlenko _"First of all Australia has 3 times zones. +10 means EST (Sydney/Melbourne). At this moment we are on Daylightsavings time which is +11 hours."_ ? Not certain how this relates to actual Question ?: _"not sure how to go about enforcing the toLocaleDateString AND converting the date to yyyy-MM-dd."_ Set timezone to one appropriate for expected results ; though "yyyy-mm-dd" format appear to be gist of Question ?

Comment: It's not clear to me: How should date in yyyy-MM-dd be shown? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 20):

Try using `fr-CA` that returns the format in `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```js
var yyyymmdd = (new Date ()).toLocaleDateString ("fr-CA");
console.log (yyyymmdd);
```

Comment: Sure ill get my hand smacked for this, but logged in just to upvote.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the local date (GMT+10 in your case), you need to use methods of `Date`:

```
function toHtmlDate (d) {
  return (d.getFullYear() + '-0' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-0' + d.getDate()).replace(/-0(\d\d)/g, '-$1');
}
```

---

If you need an ISO date (GMT), you can use `new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)`. For explanation:

- `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString` output depends on your locale, using string splitting on it might not work for another user
- `Date.prototype.toISOString` always returns `####-##-##T##:##:##.###<timezone>`, for example `2015-10-18T23:23:22.880Z`. Take the first 10 characters, you have `<year>-<month>-<date>`.

Answer (score 3):

With `toISOString` and `slice`:

```js
var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
console.log(today)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from solution mentined:

If you have jQuery UI loaded:

```
// jQuery UI datepicker
$.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", new Date())
```

If you have Moment.JS

```
// Moment JS
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

If you need additional tools for parsing, formatting, comaping dates or converting them between time zones, I recommend to have a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library.