# How to disable the prev button in FullCalendar from Angular 7 typecsript

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have been stuck on this, i want to disable the previous button on FullCalendar if i go 2 months back.

Well this is April so if i go to Feb after that the prev button should be disabled.
I have implemented the FullCalendar but cannot implement this as all the solutions so far have been in JQuery.

Please guide me as i have implemented it for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FullCalendar has a [`validRange`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange) property that accepts date range in the following format:

```
{
  start: '2017-05-01',
  end: '2017-06-01'
}
```

You could then leverage [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) function with locale [`fr-CA`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55291244/6513921) that returns the date in our desired format `yyyy-MM-dd`. Try the following

Template

```html
<full-calendar
  #calendar
  defaultView="dayGridMonth"
  [header]="{
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
  }"
  eventLimit="true"
  [validRange]="validRange"
  [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
  [weekends]="calendarWeekends"
  [events]="calendarEvents"
  (dateClick)="handleDateClick($event)"
  (eventClick)="eventClicked($event)"
></full-calendar>
```

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  validRange = { start: '', end: '' };
  .
  .
  ngOnInit() {
    let startDate =  new Date();
    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 2);  // <-- adjust number of months here
    this.validRange.start = startDate.toLocaleDateString("fr-CA");
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-example-ogsb1c)